# TarArchiveOutputStream is not archiving hidden files

Tags: java, tar, apache-commons

I have noticed that the TarArchiveOutputStream is not archiving the hidden files. Is there any way to compress these files as well?

Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: "compress" - note that a tar-archive does not compress data. It just groups them into one file, no compression algorithm whatsoever.

Comment: I think we need to see your code to see what's happening - as it is we can't even be sure if you're trying to create an archive or extract files out of an archive

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't make sense. `TarArchiveInputStream` is used to *read* tar archives. It doesn't archive them. Do you mean `TarArchiveOutputStream`?

`TarArchiveOutputStream` does include hidden files when you use it, unless you explicitly filter them out.

Comment: @ELEVATE sorry for the typo. I meant to ask for TarArchiveOutputStream

Comment: If you have a problem, please post a highly-simplified example so we can reproduce it. Your question is too vague as it stands.